Can a REST API which is not brought behind APIM, have its configuration stored in Azure App Configuration?
Given that I have a project structure where I have an angular application which talks to REST API which talks to Azure Function Apps which talks to COSMOS and GREMLIN databases to get the data. The architecture is such that Azure function App are brought behind APIM and in vNET, to have API-level access and network level access controls respectively. The REST APIs on the other hand are behind none. My architect might have reasons one of which I remember is that it is not directly interacting with database and maybe there is no necessity. But then the other part is, the application configuration of REST APIs cannot be stored on Azure App Configuration. For this it seems private endpoints are required and for that it is to be brought behind vNET (assumption)?? So, a public facing REST API cannot really have its configuration stored in Azure app configuration?

You don't have to use private endpoints for App Configuration. App Configuration does support public network access.
